# Stripe - How To Add Product Behalf Of Connected Account?

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, invoice

Normally when using stripe I can create products and add tax rates, shipping rates. After the payment I can create invoice. I want to do the same thing when using connected account. In my app I want users to create stores and this stores' product will be saved to their connected stripe account. Stores in my app will set shipping rates and tax rates. Then I can automatically invoice the payment. That's what I want to do. Is it possible to do with stripe? Because I read the documents but I could not understand the invoicing on connected accounts. Because when invoicing the connected account only `customer id` required. That confused me.

[Invoice connected accounts document](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/invoices)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do things exactly how you describe but I'd suggest you reach out to Support to talk about this further: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email